# How to install Nvidia drivers version 440 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, xorg

I'd like to ask how to install `nvidia-driver-440` properly on Ubuntu 20.04. I have an old GTX 760 graphics card, and I want to use CUDA 10.2 which is not possible with the default `nvidia-driver-450`.

But when I try to downgrade the driver with first removing the old one and then `$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440`, it doesn't work so well. After rebooting, my screen is weirdly distorted and on a much lower resolution. `nvidia-smi` fails with:

```
Error: failed to initialize. NVML driver/library version mismatch.
```

When I go back to 450, everything is normal again. I repeated this a few times and when looking closer at the command outputs during installation, I noticed it said that some modules failed to initialize because their version is not bigger as the ones in the kernel (which is 450). They suggest to override this with --force, which I tried (`$ sudo apt-get --force install nvidia-driver-440`) but it also fails.

My question is: What can I do now? Do I really have to downgrade to Ubuntu 18 or is there a way to get version 440 working on Ubuntu 20?

Comment: I've faced with the same issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320798/cannot-install-nvidia-driver-440-on-ubuntu-20-04 ... still have not found solution, switched back to 18.04 LTS

Comment: Yeah, me too sadly :(